# Material UI Textfield Label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, label, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to scale a text field in Material UI so that it is responsive to changes in window dimensions. I have been able to scale the actual textfield size, but when I do the label no longer sits correctly in the textfield like so: 
[image]

This is the code I use to create the textfield

```html
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        options={top100Films.map(option => option.title)}
        renderInput={params => (
            <TextField {...params}  label="Search for places, events or lists" variant="outlined"
                InputLabelProps={{
                    style: {
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        fontSize: '1vw', 
                    }, 
                }}
                InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: 
                    <InputAdornment position="end"><SearchIcon style={{fontSize:'1.5vw'}}/></InputAdornment>,
                    style: {
                      padding: '0.5vw',
                    },
                    
                }}
                inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps,
                  style: {
                    padding: '0.5vw',
                    height: '1vw',
                  }
                }}
            />
        )} {...props} />
```

Has anyone had issues with making a textfield dynamic and would know how to go about this issue?

Comment: You should use the breakpoints from the themeProvider if the screen size is the issue. If you can provide a working codesanbox I could help you further

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?